# regex match with or without tail after certain character

Tags: regex, shell

I want to match the rule with or without redundant string in the end. And swap the match patterns.
Example:

```
$　"aaa bbb ccc"　--> "bbb aaa"
$ "aaa bbb" --> "bbb aaa"
```

Here is what I tried but does not work.

```
echo "aaa bbb ccc" | sed -e 's:\(.*\)\s\(.*\)(\s\(.*\))?:\2\s\1:g'
$ aaa bbb ccc
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using sed

Try:

```
$ echo "aaa bbb" | sed -Ee 's:([[:alnum:]]+)[[:space:]]+([[:alnum:]]+).*:\2 \1:'
bbb aaa
$ echo "aaa bbb ccc" | sed -Ee 's:([[:alnum:]]+)[[:space:]]+([[:alnum:]]+).*:\2 \1:'
bbb aaa
```

Notes:

1. sed recognizes POSIX regular expressions.  `\s` is a GNU-only extension.  Character classes like `[[:space:]]` and `[[:alnum:]]` are understand by all implementations of sed.
2. I added the option `-E` to get extended regular expressions.  That eliminates the need for the backslashes and it also enables to the use of `+` to mean one or more.
3. There is no need to match parts of the line after the words that you want to exchange.

#### Using bash

```
$ read a b c<<<"aaa bbb"; echo "$b $a"
bbb aaa
$ read a b c<<<"aaa bbb ccc"; echo "$b $a"
bbb aaa
```

#### Using awk

```
$ echo "aaa bbb" | awk '{print $2,$1}'
bbb aaa
$ echo "aaa bbb ccc" | awk '{print $2,$1}'
bbb aaa
```

Comment: I am sorry that I asked the question wrong. The output should not contain "ccc" at the end of the string. I updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: @LionLai OK.  See updated answer for methods that also eliminate `ccc`.

Answer (score 0):

**awk** solution:

```
echo aaa bbb | awk '{print $2" "$1}'
echo aaa bbb ccc | awk '{print $2" "$1}'
```

what it does is just print the 1st and the 2nd fields in the reverse order ignoring the rest of the lines: elements are identified by the default `FS` of `awk` that can be adapted to your needs

[image]

Hope it helps you!